# Identifying user triggering ArcGIS Server invalid username or password error

Tags: arcgis-server, security

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to identify the culprit of an "Invalid Username or Password" error in ArcGIS Server logs? For source, it just says 'Admin' for source, and nothing for User. Is there a .txt log stored somewhere that would tell me which username is causing the bad login?

Comment: Might be a long shot or already done, but for your log settings, do you have it set for the most detail?  I think it is verbose.

Comment: An Invalid Username or Password error (6974) is a Severe error... Verbose includes Severe errors, but still only the amount of detail I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be able to now that I have read up a bit on the documentation.  It looks like you can check **User Name** if you set it up in the **Logging Properties**.  Check the documentation [HERE](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Viewing_querying_and_configuring_server_logs/01540000043r000000/) to find more details.

From what I am gathering, you just need to add a property.  You also could look into setting your **Logging Level** to **Debug** if you can't get the information through the properties.

This is for 10.1 so hopefully your version is around there.

Comment: I can view the User column... there is nothing listed. Also, when I query with Debug as the setting, I do not see anything past the last hour, even though my query details I have set to the last 24 hours...